# Getting Linux Service Information By using Python Code (Performance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, service, systemd

I need to get some service information by using Python code. I want to run this code with a very very low CPU consumption.

Here is the simplified code:

```
import subprocess, time

start_time = time.time()

command1 = "systemctl show alsa-restore.service --property=LoadState,UnitFileState,ActiveState,SubState"
command2 = "systemctl show apt-daily.service --property=LoadState,UnitFileState,ActiveState,SubState"
command3 = "systemctl show cryptdisks-early.service --property=LoadState,UnitFileState,ActiveState,SubState"
commands = command1 + "\n" + command2 + "\n" + command3

output = subprocess.check_output(commands, shell=True).decode()

end_time = time.time()

print(end_time-start_time)
```

Actual code has a lot of services and this code runs very frequently.
What may work this code run faster? Are there any other ways to get this information faster?

```
System: Debian-like Linux x64, Python: 3.9
```

Comment: A couple possible suggestions: run ```systemctl``` to show status for all services, and parse the output. Running multiple commands in a subprocess does have some overhead. Also may be able to adapt the techniques [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/694818/get-notification-when-systemd-monitored-service-enters-fa) to update service status somewhere you can access it more efficiently.

Comment: I have already used ```systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --all --no-pager``` command but sometimes I need to get some additional information which is not provided in the output of the same command.